# memory leak with method NSRegularExpression.matchesInString()

Tags: swift, memory-leaks

I have realized that the method matchesInString has a memory leak. 
Am I doing something wrong, or is this really a core method that leaks ?
If it leaks, what is the alternativ using regular expression ? (I know I could code all my self, but I am looking for something reusable)
My code just tries to cut out some specific parameters of a String.

```
    print ("Memory Leak Test ");
    for var i in 1...1000000 {

        print("Memory Leak Test " + String(i));

        let sMyString:String="opacity:0.71889403;fill:#0000ff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#0000ff;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1;display:inline\"/></svg>"
        var stringsuche:String = "fill:(.*?);";
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: stringsuche, options: [])
        let results = regex.matchesInString(sMyString, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, sMyString.length))
    }
    print("End  Memory Leak Test ");
```

**UPDAT**
I simply wrote my own code for this, but this experience gives me a bad feeling. I guess there are a lot of core methods that are leaking. Just found out that "stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet" & "stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString" also leaks !

```
func getstylevalue(styleprop:String, text:String) -> String{

    var returnvalue="";

    let stringsuche:String=styleprop;
    let indexstart=text.indexOf(stringsuche);
    if indexstart == -1 {
        return returnvalue;
    }else{
        let indexend=text.indexOf(";", startIndex: indexstart) ;
        if indexend == -1 {
            return returnvalue;
        }else{
            returnvalue=text.substring(indexstart + stringsuche.length, endIndex: indexend);
            return returnvalue;
        }
    }
}
```

Memory leak with trimming:

```
print("Start  Memory Leak Test ");
for i in 1...1000000 {
    let theword:String="     bla     ";
    let temp:String = theword.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
}
print("End  Memory Leak Test ");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this Swift code leak memory, and how do I handle it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34102189/why-does-this-swift-code-leak-memory-and-how-do-i-handle-it)

Answer (score 1):

Try `autoreleasepool {}` to workaround the memory cycle (leak) issue.

```
extension String {

    func regexSearch(pattern pattern: String) -> [String] {
        let nsString: NSString = NSString(UTF8String: self)!
        var stringGroupMatches = [String]()

        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
            let nsRangeAll = NSRange(location: 0, length: nsString.length)

            autoreleasepool {
                let matches = regex.matchesInString( nsString as String, options: [], range: nsRangeAll) 

                for match: NSTextCheckingResult in matches {
                    let rangeCount = match.numberOfRanges
                    // remember: $0th match is whole pattern
                    for group in 0 ..< rangeCount {
                        let r: NSRange = match.rangeAtIndex(group)
                        stringGroupMatches.append(nsString.substringWithRange(r))
                    }
                }
            }
            return stringGroupMatches
        }
        catch {
            return []
        }
    }

}
```